# Given E(X) and Var(X) find the Expectation of $E[x-2(X-1)^2]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a r.v. with $E(X) = 5$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X) = 30$. Find $E[X-2(X-1)^2]$.

I'm not sure as to how to approach this problem, any tips on how to approach it would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Use linearity of expectation and write the variance in terms of an expectation.  Substitute the variance into the expression first to eliminate the quadratic term.  Then the remainder is just an expectation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X)=E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2-2XE[X]+E[X]^2]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2.
$$
Therefore, $E[X^2]=\operatorname{Var}(X)+E[X]^2$.  Then,
$$
E[X-2(X-1)^2]=E[X-2(X^2-2X+1)]=E[-2X^2+5X-2]=-2E[X^2]+5E[X]-2.
$$
Now, substitute for variance and expectation.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X) &= \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 \\
\mathbb{E}[X-2(X-1)^2] &= \mathbb{E}[X-2(X^2-2X+1)] = \mathbb{E}[- 2X^2 + 5X - 2] \\
&= -2\mathbb{E}[X^2] + 5\mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[2] \quad \textrm{(by linearity)}.
\end{align}